# R writing to file from linux

Tags: linux, windows, r

I have below code. I am writing to a text file using capture.output command. When I run this command in the Windows R, I get a nice output with a tabular structure. But the same command produces a kind of ugly output in Linux R...any idea how to fix it?

```
fileConn<-file("ch7data_metadata.txt","w+")
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
columninfo <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
capture.output(columninfo, file = fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Comment: Looks nice to me on my Linux box.  Does `file.show("ch7data_metadata.txt")` look ugly?

Comment: Why not use `write.table`?

Comment: @GSee file.show() shows a proper output...but when R writes to txt file, it doesnt maintain the spacing and new lines :(

Comment: `file.show` is showing you the text file that _was written by R_.  What text editor are you using to view the file when it doesn't look right?  (e.g. I bet `nano ch7data_metadata.txt` would look fine)

Comment: @GSee notepad.....which one should i use?

Comment: @GSee i am also writing a few more lines to the file. Those lines are not in tabular format...do you think that these lines could be causing the problem?

Comment: i am opening that file is windows...i have to run the  code in linux but users are going to see that output file in windows...i cannot run code on windows for some valid reason

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/71507/convert-unix-line-endings-to-windows

Comment: FWIW, it looks fine in Notepad++ on Windows.

Comment: notepad++ or opening in a browser works...thanks!